# Where is the private feedback on a question closed as offtopic?

Tags: support, closed-questions

My former question (not essential to this one here) was marked as Offtopic.

[Is it possible to change screen brightness via console? Autohotkey use welcome, OS is Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60575098/is-it-possible-to-change-screen-brightness-via-console-autohotkey-use-welcome)

As I would like to improve, it would help to know what exactly is off topic (not about programming, ...). It tells me about private feedback, but I'm unable to find or read it. Sorry if this sounds stupid, but I was looking for it maybe half an hour.

In the Question:

> Closed. This question is *off-topic*. It is not currently accepting answers.
>
> *Update the question* so it's *on-topic* for Stack Overflow.
>
> Closed yesterday by *[3 Users]*.
>
> (Private feedback for you)

(I would expect for example that "private feedback" was a link)

In the [Stackoverflow help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) also just the statement of existance:

> If your question is closed, you will receive private feedback on the reason why it was closed.

Answer (score 31):

The Stack Exchange developers recently re-worked the UI surrounding question closure. The current notification message is terrible and confusing. It is trying to say that the information you see in the blue box above the line "(Private feedback for you)" *is* the private feedback for you. I don't know how this change ever passed approval. It literally makes no sense, and it has been confusing users ever since it rolled out. I am very sorry that you were caught by this.

Compounding matters further is that your question was closed without a consensus. The three users who voted to close it each chose three different reasons for it to be closed, which means that the system has *no* detailed information/feedback to provide to you. It could do a better job at informing you of this, and indeed it used to, but it doesn't any more.

This redesign of the closure notification system was intended to make the site more "welcoming". Instead, it has resulted in confusion and annoyance all around. I don't know how this ever happened, but the fact that it did proves that the development and deployment processes at Stack Exchange headquarters are still fundamentally broken.

Regarding [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60575098/is-it-possible-to-change-screen-brightness-via-console-autohotkey-use-welcome), it's not even off-topic. I've made a few edits to improve its clarity, and have re-opened it.

Comment: I deleted my answer here  as it factually wrong... I need to ask some bad questions... That would let me learn new UI and allow people to revenge downvote (as they have to downvote not too awful questions now :) ).

Comment: Well, certainly part of your answer was correct. In particular, the part that said: *"but often question's author ignore such suggestions or react in unpleasant ways."* There's plenty of blame to go around. The UI could certainly stand to be improved in order to communicate information more effectively to the asker, but your experience matches mine where the asker all too frequently becomes combative and hostile towards the people who are trying to help them.

Comment: I said somewhere else in a comment that these (hints) were added in the UI mock up only to be meant as a reminder for the designer / developers what their functional purpose was. Then someone was tasked with "implement these new post notices conforming to these specs and mock up. As it took 6 to 8 weeks to get them designed, stick to them, no discussion, implement it as proposesd"  and the dev said "Okay". And here we are.

Comment: It might also be a matter of badly managed expectations. If private feedback is promised like this one might expect a bit more than just a single line, possibly even some personalized comments.

Comment: I actually like the new closure notifications. ... "proves that the development and deployment processes at Stack Exchange headquarters are still fundamentally broken." ... that's far fetched ...

Comment: The veterans like them just fine, @Jonas, because we don't actually pay attention to them. We don't read what they say or try to understand what they mean because we already [think we] know. I'm not sure what it is you like about them, but they're certainly not clear or understandable to new users.

Comment: exactly @Trilarion I mean, I thought someone wanted to say something without being inflammatory, hence a "private" message.  Just closing a message isn't really "private" to my thinking.  Sigh.  Whatever.  Okay, longer thought:  if the notion is to be friendler than maybe say:  because you're new, the q is kept open an extra few days to give a chance to improve the question.  or something.

Answer (score 9):

The private feedback part is the area below the light horizontal line.

Here's how this section is viewed by different users:

### Yourself / Post owner:

[image]

### Logged-in users with the close vote privilege (>=3000 reputation):

[image]

### Anonymous guests (logged out users), and users who do not have close vote privileges

- this group do not see the "*private feedback*", which is the users who voted to close the question:

[image]

Comment: @Genius, The images here accurately show the difference in what's displayed for the question OP's question on SO. However, with respect to your comment, unfortunately, the images, and the original question here, are from a question which just lists "off-topic" as the close reason. For a question which had some consensus wrt. the close reason and was closed for a reason *other than* "request for off-site resource" or a custom close reason, there is additional text displayed to the OP which does include some hints as to what's wrong. With >3k rep, you should see that text on closed questions.

Comment: @Makyen I meant it as a bit of a joke, but it seems my use of "genius" hasn't translated very well. I apologise.

Comment: @TiiJ7 It looks like I may have misread you comment. I can't see deleted comments, so I'm not sure. However, my intent was merely to correct what I thought was a misunderstanding that the new post notices are this unhelpful in all circumstances. At a minimum, it looks like I put the wrong username in the `@` ping. I, also, am sorry for any miscommunication. OTOH, I do agree with the sentiment you expressed that the "private feedback" is particularly unhelpful in these cases. While I don't think the new post noces are perfect, under other circumstances they are better than what's seen here.

Comment: Dang, I really need to do a better job of proofreading my comments. *sigh* s/you/your/ s/noces/notices/